# Is np.linalg.solve() not working for AutoDiff?

Tags: drake

Does np.linalg.solve() not work for AutoDiff?  I use is to solve manipulator equation. The error message is shown below.
I try a similar "double" version code, it is no issue. Please tell me how to fix it, thanks!

```
### here is the error message                        
vdot_ad = np.linalg.solve(M_,ggg_ad) 
    File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 5, in solve
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/linalg/linalg.py", line 394, in solve
    r = gufunc(a, b, signature=signature, extobj=extobj)
    TypeError: No loop matching the specified signature and casting was found for ufunc solve1

####. here is the code 
plant = MultibodyPlant(time_step= 0.01)
parser = Parser(plant)
parser.AddModelFromFile("double_pendulum.sdf")
plant.Finalize()
plant_autodiff = plant.ToAutoDiffXd()

####### <AutoDiff> get the error message
xu = np.hstack((x, u))
xu_ad = initializeAutoDiff(xu)[:,0]
x_ad = xu_ad[:4]
q_ad = x_ad[:2]
v_ad = x_ad[2:4]
u_ad = xu_ad[4:]
(M_, Cv_, tauG_, B_, tauExt_) = ManipulatorDynamics(plant_autodiff, q_ad, v_ad)
vdot_ad = np.linalg.solve(M_,tauG_ + np.dot(B_,u_ad) - np.dot(Cv_,v_ad))
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't realize that `np.linalg.solve` doesn't work for autodiff. I would recommend that instead of computing `vdot_ad` by yourself, you could call `plant_autodiff.CalcTimeDerivatives`, which calls a function in C++. The C++ function works with Eigen's autodiff scalars. For more information on using CalcTimeDerivatives, you could refer to our tutorial https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/RobotLocomotion/drake/blob/nightly-release/tutorials/dynamical_systems.ipynb

Comment: BTW, I rewrote the code in the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64565023/how-to-get-a-dynamic-which-we-can-be-applied-gradient-in-the-next-step-re-open/64565582#64565582 to use `CalcTimeDerivatives`. Notice that the plant is created as a continuous time system (dt=0).

Comment: Yes, it is strange. I already work on this for a half day,  vdot_ad = np.linalg.solve(M_,tauG_ + np.dot(B_,u_ad) - np.dot(Cv_,v_ad)).  Maybe I miss something.  I will check it again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that in pydrake, `AutoDiffXd` scalars are exposed to NumPy using `dtype=object`.

There are some drawbacks to this approach, like what you have ran into now. 
This is not necessarily an issue with Drake, but a limitation on NumPy itself given the ufunc's that are implemented on the (super old) version that is on 18.04.

To illustrate, here is what I see on Ubuntu 18.04, CPython 3.6.9, NumPy 1.13.3:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> A = np.eye(2)
>>> b = np.array([1, 2])
>>> np.linalg.solve(A, b)
array([ 1.,  2.])
>>> A = A.astype(object)
>>> b = b.astype(object)
>>> np.linalg.solve(A, b)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/linalg/linalg.py", line 375, in solve
    r = gufunc(a, b, signature=signature, extobj=extobj)
TypeError: No loop matching the specified signature and casting
was found for ufunc solve1
```

The most direct solution would be to expose an analogous routine in `pydrake`, and have users leverage that.

That is what we had to do for `np.linalg.inv` as well: 
https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/pull/11173/files

Not the best solution :( However, it's simple enough!

Comment: Posted an issue here: https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/issues/14264

Comment: Posted PR: https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/pull/14266

Comment: Ah, forgot to say too: If you're formulating constraints, always consider the more implicit form! e.g. `M v = ...`. For an example, see Eq. (24) here: http://groups.csail.mit.edu/robotics-center/public_papers/Posa15.pdf